# R Shiny and p5.js

Tags: shiny, p5.js

I am using R Shiny to develop a web page and also include my own R code.

I am using p5.js(https://p5js.org/) to display a game in the web page.

As in the official web page says I have an HTML and the p5 javascript code together with the javascript library. If I run the HTML, that is, clicking right and pressing chrome to display I get the started example (https://p5js.org/get-started/) with no incidence.

Here it is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">-->
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libraries/p5.js">    </script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
  <!-- this line removes any default padding and style. you might only need one of these values set. -->
  <style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} </style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

When I do the same in Shiny, running the code from R-Studio I do not get anything from it. I have stored the javascript files in the www folder as it is supposed to be and I currently know that my HTML called the javascript since I set an alert in the p5 javascript file, but outside the setup and draw methods. The problem is that, even though the alert is loaded, seems like the setup and draw methods are not called and, obviously, as a consequence, they do not load the canvas. I know that they are not called because I have a called to an alert in the setup method that works running the HTML file directly but not if I run the same file from R-Studio.

Here it is the p5 javascript code:

```
alert("GOOD1");

function setup() {
  alert("GOOD2");
  createCanvas(640, 480);
}

function draw() {
  if (mouseIsPressed) {fill(0);} 
  else {fill(255);}
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 80, 80);
}
```

I load the HTML page in Shiny using the next line of code

```
... ,tabItem(tabName = "tabProcessing", htmlOutput("processingMasterThesis") ...
```

Attach to the tag "processingMasterThesis" I have the corresponding URL to the HTML file in the server.R, as it is supposed to be so the problem is not here.

Why may be the cause of this? It works if I call the HTML file directly to be load in the browser but not if I do it from R-Studio, why?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Hi @Kevin Workman, thank you for answering. I get this warning when I try to load the webpage: `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`.  In my javascript file I do not use this request call directly but maybe the p5js library does internally. It seems the problem is here but if it it is so, why I get this error when I run from RStudio the web page (what I actually run from RStudio is the ui.R file) and not when I load the HTML file with a right-click?

Comment: I have solved the problem. First I have to create a variable in the p5js file that I can reference from the HTML, lets say canvas = createCanvas(640, 480);. Once I have my global variable declared I just have to tell it its parent, lets say myCanvas.parent("divCanvas");. After this you just have to create either in shiny or pure html a code like this: # THE UI
      ,tags$html(tags$body(
        tags$head(tags$script(src = "app/libraries/p5.js"))
        ,tags$head(tags$script(src = "app/sketch.js"))
        ,tags$div(id = 'divCanvas')
      ))

Comment: Sounds good. You might want to post an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Ah oks! I didn't know here on this web page there was a difference between a comment and an answer xdd, fail... I will post the answer right away kevin.

Comment: Oh it's not a big deal, but if you post an answer then you might help somebody with a similar problem in the future. Plus you might get some upvotes :p

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. The p5 java script code will be:

```
// =====================
// "app/sketch.js"
// =====================
var myCanvas;

function setup() {
  var idCanvas = 'divCanvas';
  myCanvas = createCanvas(300, 300);
  myCanvas.parent(idCanvas);
}

function draw() {
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    fill(0);
  } else {
    fill(255);
  }
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 80, 80);
}
```

The library you need to run the example can be found at https://p5js.org/

In this javascript file I have created an id that reference a html div element so that is the place where I will set my canvas. Once this is done, the rest of the javascript code will code perfectly. The point is to reference that the parent of the canvas is that div as you can see in the code.

After this you just have to create either in shiny or pure html code something like this:

```
# THE UI (File ui.R)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rmarkdown)

shinyUI(
fluidRow(
  # THE UI
  tags$html(
    tags$body(
    singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src = "master_thesis/app/libraries/p5.js")))
    ,singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src = "master_thesis/app/sketch.js")))
    ,singleton(tags$div(id = 'divCanvas', style = 'width:auto; height:auto'))
))
)
)
```

The code that I show below is in shiny. The first "head" line include the library p5.js and the second "head" line just say "hey this is my p5 script file" and "divCanvas will be the div that I will print on".

You may have issues with the references to the javascript file. I think is worthy to note that you must create a www folder in your root shiny application. In this folder, you must put your javascript files. For example, as you can see in my code the two javascript files that I am using follow the next path:

```
ShinyApplication/www/app/libraries/p5.js
ShinyApplication/www/app/sketch.js
```

Hope this can help!

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a little bit? I think I get it, but am not clear on the output type for `ui.R`... could you fill in the structure of the UI a bit more, like where those arguments go, if one needs something like `htmlOutput` for example?

Comment: Good morning @Hendy, you just need a tag like div to store the canvas and make a reference to it from the javascript file which must be previously set in the head. With the current code, that is the answer, you can run directly P5.js from RShiny. Of course, you must place the javascript files in the directories that I indicate in the answer to make it work.